# Visa process Indian visiting Egypt

Tags: indian-citizens, egypt

I am an Indian passport holder. I have a 2-year Schengen visa and am in France right now. I need to visit Egypt this week. What visa formalities are required for an Indian passport holder?

Answer (score 1):

Your Schengen Visa doesn't play a role for Egyptian Visa.

[You will need to obtain a visa for Egypt](http://www.mfa.gov.eg/english/ConsularServices/Pages/ConsularServiceDetails.aspx?ID=Visa+Application) according to the Ministry of the Foreign affairs of Egypt.

You should be able to do this at the [Embassy in Paris](http://www.ambassade-egypte.fr/) or it may be possible if you're traveling as part of [the tourist group](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/country/egypt.html) that you won't have to.

Comment: is your last link correct? The statement on that page could be true for US passport holders only, not Indian passport holders.

Comment: Ah, found another reference for it [here](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=EG&user=EK&subuser=EMIRATES): Visa required, except for Nationals of India traveling as a part of an organized tourist group, provided: 
- The tourist group consists of at least 10 persons; and:
- Holding a return ticket, booked accommodation and a signed guarantee letter from a travel agency.

Comment: @mkennedy Didn't use Timatic but 1st link basically is for any country.